# SQL query to return only first occurance of one column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am not sure how to ask this question... but here it goes.

I have a table called `lists` that has four columns, `id`, `name`, `type`, and `group`. The `type` column values are not unique and is a text column. I need a query to return `id` and `type` from table `lists`, but I only need one of each `type`. It should also be in alphabetical order. It can be the first occurrence of each type.

In postgreSQL 9.4.5 I have tried `select distinct list_type, id from lists order by list_type;`, but this of course returns duplicate types that have unique ids.

I only need the first occurrence of each `type` and that `id`.

Some sample data:

```
                  id                  |           type            
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------
 0014dea9-f73f-46d0-bf7d-d52717029582 | invest_fees
 004665b5-4657-4cbc-8534-1aa9e4ef305f | invest_fees
 00910f6c-bdf0-4991-ac0c-969b3b9c6b84 | invest_fees
 009ed283-531b-4d7b-b51d-0c0e0e7a5707 | countries
 00b4f8e2-ae47-4083-ae6e-8d6dbaa2cd63 | invest_fees
 00ca1972-cf70-4fa2-bfde-bc89fce19433 | invest_fees
 00feb6a2-4ee7-4e31-8780-cb5938587669 | countries
 010777bc-7e74-4c13-8808-4c35cfdbf988 | pick_banks
 01852693-7560-4de5-a534-0519e7c04c51 | countries
 01bee5a4-23f7-427d-9b84-4c707154a812 | countries
 01bf29f9-70af-4b3c-b7f9-d01e0f0f142c | invest_fees
 01d51fe3-4c32-4d21-b38c-8e84a92ff0aa | invest_fees
 01d981dd-13d4-4098-a7e3-bd1bb5f02f2b | countries
 01de77bb-ff82-4c3c-b26f-f3829d84dd29 | invest_fees
 01df6e6c-9a77-4b83-a825-09949768df54 | countries
 01f11d01-f490-48a9-b21c-803f7c03f5f6 | invest_mtos
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `row_number` function to get one `id` (ordered ascending) per `type`.

```
select id, type from 
(
select id, name, type, "group", 
row_number() over(partition by type order by type) as rn
from lists
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks vkp, but I am still getting duplicate types... they have unique ids. Listing the first occurence of the type is more important than listing unique ids. All of my ids are unique, but I am not concerned with listing all ids and their type.

Comment: please post some sample data from the table

Answer (score 3):

In postgres you can use

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (type) type, many, other, columns FROM lists ORDER BY type ASC;
```

This should select only as many rows as there are different types. In your case there would be only one row where the type is `invest_fees`

You can read more about selections with `DISTINC ON` right [here](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-select-distinct/)

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(id) as id, list_type
from lists
group by list_type
order by list_type
```

Answer (score 0):

You want one result row per type. This translates to `GROUP BY type` in SQL.

Then you say you don't care which of its IDs you get per type, so use `MIN` or `MAX`, it doesn't matter:

```
select list_type, min(id) as one_of_its_ids
from lists 
group by list_type
order by list_type;
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't see Clodoaldo Neto's answer when I wrote mine. You notice it's the same answer actually. vkp's answer does about the same with the difference that more work is done and the ID retrieved is more random. You would use this kind of query when there was a ranking needed or you wanted more columns from the same record. Otherwise go with Clodoaldo Neto's answer; it's the straight-forward way to the problem given.